# How to upload image from assets in flutter to firebase storage?

Tags: image, firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I am using below code to select image from gallery to upload to Firebase Storage in Flutter application, but I want that if the user doesn't select an image, a default image from the assets should be uploaded to the firebase storage. What code should I write for the image to be selected from assets and it is set equal to `File avatarImageFile` so that it can be uploaded to Firebase storage in flutter application

```
File avatarImageFile;
    Future getImage() async {
        File image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

        if (image != null) {
          setState(() {
            avatarImageFile = image;
            isLoading = true;
          });
        }

        uploadFile();
      }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can convert Asset image to File then upload to Firebase!
Here is code to convert:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

Future<File> getImageFileFromAssets(String path) async {
  final byteData = await rootBundle.load('assets/$path');

  final file = File('${(await getTemporaryDirectory()).path}/$path');
  await file.writeAsBytes(byteData.buffer.asUint8List(byteData.offsetInBytes, byteData.lengthInBytes));

  return file;
}
```

In your example, you would call this function like this:

`File f = await getImageFileFromAssets('images/myImage.jpg');`

and edit your code:

```
File avatarImageFile;

    Future getImage() async {
        File f = await getImageFileFromAssets('path of your asset Image');
        File image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);


      if (image != null) {
        setState(() {
          avatarImageFile = image;
          isLoading = true;
        });
      }else{
        avatarImageFile = f;
        isLoading = true;
      }

        uploadFile();
      }
```

Comment: Getting Error. Any solution please: PathNotFoundException: Cannot open file, path = '/data/user/0/com.example.t_store/cache/icons/categories/icons8-bowling-64.png' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2).